# Escape single quotes in order to add a comma between values

Tags: javascript, string

I need to replicate the following parameters:

```
const data = MyModel.query().select('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Each field is single quoted and separated by comma.
Is possible to do it with a `variable`?

Tried using `\` but couldn't succeed.

e.g:

```
const fields = "\'"tab1.val1"\', tab2.val2"  

const fields = "field1\', 'field2'"
```

Comment: You mean you want to replace `select('field1', 'field2', 'field3')` with `select(fields)`?

Comment: I need to replace use a variable to write what is inside `select`. `'field1', 'field2', 'field3'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace

```
.select('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

with

```
.select(fields)
```

then you can't do that
but you could put all the fields in an array and then use spread syntax to pass the array elements as discrete arguments to `select` method.

```
const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];

const data = MyModel.query().select(...fields);
```